# Error Message on executing MSI after creation

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, windows-installer

I am trying to create a MSI Setup for a WPF Project for the first time using the "Setup Project" Template in Visual Studio 2022, but unfortunately I receive an error when running the created MSI.

In general it is quite straigt forward. After project creation I added the Project output to be transfered to the MSI and ran the build. The log output seems ok.
But running the MSI results in the message

```
"The path ... contains an invalid character"
```

(translated from the german "Der Pfad .. enthält ein ungültiges Zeichen").

From the Event log I got the information that it is a Error 1324 but nothing further.

Is it necessary to make a path configuration somewhere? I couldn't find anything related.
Any ideas?

Comment: What matters is which path has a problem, such as: error 1324 the path My Documents contains an invalid character. At this time, you need to use the regedit command to open the registry editor and locate to "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]" to view the right window, and change the path of the Personal item to the current user's "My Documentation" path.